# Two counts in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I do two separate counts in the same cell?

For example, I want to have cell to have two values *from separate* counts.

Something like `29 - 14` in the same cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate two separate counts and show them as text in the same cell. For example,

```
=COUNTA(D1:D100)&" - "&COUNTA(F1:F25)
```

[image]

Comment: what about COUNTIF statements chuff? how about putting 2 together?

Comment: Sure. All you really need is two expressions that each resolve to a single value, which you then concatenate with a dash between them.

Answer (score 1):

I from what you have stated understand that there are two numbers in a single cell seperated by a hyphen (-), like 29-32 or 10-12. That you want to take each of these numbers as a count.
The simplest way is to use the following formula where you have only two values seperated by a hyphen like 29-42 or a single value like 42:
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A1,1)),1,2)
The value 29-42 is in cell A1. I have entered the above formula in cell B1. This formula finds if there is a hyphen or not. If there is hyphen then 2 is returned otherewise if there is error because of absence of hyphen then 1 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but that's very weird and will probably bring troubles.

Use text concatenation.

```
= formula1 & " - " & formula2
```

Where you read `formula1`, use any formula you want.
Where you read `formula2`, use any other formula you want.
The `&` symbol joins text. So the `& " - " &` adds the dash separating the two values.